# Finished studying and just waiting for graduation what should i put on my resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, human-resources

I studied BS Computer Science in a trimester college school and i already finish all of my subjects this sem (September 2 2016) my problem is my graduation is next year April 2017 but i already want to apply for a job my question is what should i put on my resume to explain i finish my study but because of our school system i still haven't graduated? And Is finishing all subjects but not graduated yet is common?

Comment: @gnat I think it's different problem because i already finished all my subjects and i am no longer studying i am just waiting for my graduation.

Comment: "Completed September 2016, graduating April 2017"

Comment: You are a "graduand" if that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Don't overthink this. Something like "September 2016 - BS Computer Science diploma (graduation : 04/17)" will be perfectly fine. Though it's not the most common it's definitely not unheard of, and it's unlikely to confuse the HR guy who will read your resume.

Answer (score 0):

Ero's is a good answer

> "September 2016 - BS Computer Science diploma (graduation : 04/17)"

Since it's somewhat unusual, you could add some more detail

1. Have you met ALL graduation requirements already? Is there any possibility you won't graduate?
2. Are you available for full time work right now? Is there anything left at school that you need to wrap up or that you need to take time off for?
3. Are you grades already set in stone? Can anything happen that impacts your final grades?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this a few times, I have not yet finished by BA and have it as:

> **Coolguy University** - BA/BS In Cool Guy-ism - *Project Grad Date: June 2017*

You can add an extra modifying blurb saying you Completed Studies/Study Completed, or whatever wording you prefer, and give that date. The schooling experience is what is more or less what is important.

Just be prepared to backup those claims in case an HR Manager happens to ask, that may or may not vary by Country and/or internal Company HR Policies/Directives.